# Using AJAX to contact a method on server

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to use ajax/call a webmethod in the controller by clicking a button that is in a `BeginForm`

I have a submit button in a `Html.BeginForm`. Clicking this button will as we know, send the info from the model to the server. Here is the simplified code.

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm()) 


     {
           ...
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "readonly" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "Navn skal angives", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
...

     <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Tilføj" class="btn btn-default" id="submitBut" />
                </div>
            </div>
    }
```

The corresponding Controller looks like this

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AttachCard(Card model, int MemberID)
    { ... }
```

I will need to add the annotation `[WebMethod]`

My issue is that I want to use JQuery Dialog to notify the client, when the card is added. For this I need a true or false value from the server. The dialog message will depend on this boolean value.

I have written some AJAX code. This is not tested yet, as I'm stuck

```
    function attachCard(MemberID, action, controller) {
    var url = '/' + action + '/' + controller;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: $("form").serialize(),
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "html",
        success: function (status) {
            alert("Test from server: " + status);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    })
}
```

I want this ajax function to run when the user clicks on the button that you see in my `Html.BeginForm`. But is this possible? If I add an onclick listener while it's in the `BeginForm`, then the webmethod will be called twice I think, and this will result in an exception. I am thinking about moving that button out of the `BeginForm`, and add an onclick event on the button. But then the rest of the info from the model (in the BeginForm) won't be submittet.
How can I do this?

Comment: Use `$('#submitBut').click(function(e) { e.preventDefault(); .... });` but you also need to remove the `contentType` option, and if you want a `true` or `false` then you should be returning a `JsonResult` and it will be `dataType: 'json'`

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand. Do I keep the button where it is now, or should I move it? And will the rest of the info be sent?

Comment: The button can stay where it is (the `e.preventDefault()` prevents its default action). And all success form controls will be sent using `$("form").serialize()`

Comment: Okay, I see. So I add an onclick listener on the button, which will call the webMethod? But how will the rest of the info be sent with an preventdefault? The ajax function only contains the MemberID. Is it possible to add the model in that function?

Comment: Using `$("form").serialize();` serializes all successful form controls in your `<form>` so if it contains inputs for properties of your model then they will be sent to the controller and your model will be correctly bound

Comment: Ok. I'm on it. Pleas make it so that I can accept your solution when I'm done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181938/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-mor-snow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Ajax.BeginForm instead. Here is my working sample code

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("CreateAndUpdate", "WidgetContent", new AjaxOptions
{
    OnSuccess = "GroupSubmitted",
    OnFailure = "GroupError",
}, new { role = "form", @id = "groupform" }))
{

}
```

And your Javascript callback functions

```
function GroupError(ajaxContext) {
    //Error message
}


function GroupSubmitted(result) {
  if (result.success) {

  }
  else {

  }
}
```